# What is "use 5.014002" for in perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am really a very beginner. I saw "use 5.014002;" in perl script. What does it mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It means perl version at least 5.14.2 is required to run the script. See [use](http://p3rl.org/use).

It also enables all the features (like `say`, `state` etc.) that come with the version, see [feature](http://p3rl.org/feature) or even [Syntax::Construct](http://p3rl.org/Syntax::Construct).

There are several ways how to write the version number, but this one is the most portable one, working in older versions of Perl.

Comment: More information: a long time ago, perl didn't have an x.y.z version scheme; it had versions like "4.036" and "5.004", and patch versions like "5.004_57" (underscores can be used freely for spacing in perl numeric literals, and have semi-special meaning in versions), and sometimes random things like "5.001g". Since version 5.005 was followed by 5.6.0 in 2000, perl has used x.y.z versions, but internally a version like 5.14.2 is still represented in some places like 5.014_002.

Comment: Even more information: You can `use 5.14.2` too, and that will do exactly the same thing on current perl versions. But *old* perls that don't know about that version number format will give a silly error message. Since the `use VERSION` line is useful to tell someone that their perl is too old, it makes sense to write it in a way that works even for old perls :)